# Call Fragment from fragment and on back get first one back

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

I am calling one fragment with passing bundle.

```
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putStringArrayList(Constants.Bundle.SESSION_ORDER_ID_LIST,session_order_id);
                bundle.putString(Constants.Bundle.SERVICE_ID,service_id);
                bundle.putString(Constants.Bundle.TOTAL_AMT,total_amount);
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.base_frame, CheckoutFragment.newInstance(bundle)).addToBackStack("CheckoutFragment").commit();
```

Then in checkout fragment on `TextView` click i call

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.base_frame, AddressListFragment.newInstance(bundle)).addToBackStack("AddressListFragment").commit();
```

Then In `AddressListFragment` on listview `setOnItemClickListener` i want to recall `checkoutFragment` what do i do?

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach would be to add below code in your activity

```
  /**
 * change fragment by calling from other UI parts
 *
 * @param fragment           fragment to be opened
 * @param isBackPressEnabled allow back or not
 */
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, Boolean isBackPressEnabled) {
    String tag = fragment.getClass().getCanonicalName();
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag) != null) return;
    if (isBackPressEnabled) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContainer, fragment, tag)
                .addToBackStack(tag)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.flContainer, fragment, tag)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

and call like this from your fragment

```
if (getActivity() != null) {
  ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).replaceFragment(AddressListFragment.newInstance(bundle), true);
}
```

you don't have to worry about implementation, you can change it in activity any time just add the fragment container id and you are good to go.